# EntityFramework and TPT without base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are using C# MVC .NET4. EF5 (CodeFirst).

We are trying to build a system that should dynamically allow users to "attach" extra properties to any entity.

Let's say we have ProductClass and Products. We have some "standard" fields for each entity, but the user might decide to add any arbitrary property to any record, as a Key-Value pair, like saying Product 123 has "StockMax" = "10".

Since we have many entities (+10) that might have "attached" properties, we would create single  "AttachedProperty" entity/class (in SQL that would translate to a table with PK={ParentTable, ParentId, PropertyKey}). That way we would keep a single class for the attached properties of all the entities (which would be good for building the user interface).

I see that I can accomplish that in EF by having a base class:

```
class EntityWithAttachableProperty { 
          public System.Guid Id {get;set;}
          public ICollection<MyProperty> MyProperties {get;set;} 
}
```

And then to inherit from that class to my entities, like:

```
 class Product : EntityWithAttachableProperties { 
      public string name {get;set;} 
     etc
 }
```

My issue is that I do not want to use inheritance for this. I would be forced to logically group things that are not really related. I would also get a single huge EntityWithAttachableProperties table in SQL that I do not need.

So, is there a way to accomplish TPT without the base class? (maybe through the modelbuilder). That way I would get classes like this:

```
class Product { 
     public System.Guid Id {get;set;} 
     public string name {get;set;}
     public ICollection<MyProperty> MyProperties {get;set;}
     etc
}

class ProductClass { 
     public System.Guid Id {get;set;} 
     public string Classname {get;set;}
     public ICollection<MyProperty> MyProperties {get;set;}
     etc
}
```

Note that when I do this EF tries to add Product_Id and ProductClass_Id to MyProperties table.

Comment: The `ID` columns are added to allow for a relationship between the tables.

Comment: Consider using a NoSql database. It's beneficial to use proper tools designed to do the job.

Comment: @Bob, I understand that, but that means that I would end up with +10 <something>_id column in the table. I would like to have a discriminator instead.

Comment: @JakubKonecki: you are probably correct - however, our organization is not prepared for such a change. Sounds to me that what I am trying to accomplish isn't that complex after all.

Comment: Could you just make the "attached" properties `Nullable`? So only the regular columns have to be filled in?

Comment: I do not know the properties in advance. They are supposed to be added by the users on runtime, so I cannot even add the properties to the model (thus the reason of having them in a separate entity).

Answer (score 0):

If you define the mappings for the ID columns using Fluent does it work? I am suspicious that EF will allow you to define this, but as it is a non-standard approach it is not going to assume what you are trying to do here (hence trying to map to separate ID columns). Something like this in your DbContext class (and I know this is not correct, someone might be able to improve):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(o=>o.MyProperty)
            .Map(o=>o.MapKey("Id"));
```

Comment: I understand your idea in concept - however, that doesn't add a discriminator to my attachable properties table. Also, not even sure how to implement your idea (new to EF). Thanks.